# How to consume SOAP web services in ASP.Net using proxy class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, soap

I am new in web development. I tried to consume http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx services in my web application using proxy class, But I don't have any idea how to do that? This services uses request response function.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click References --> Add Service Reference and discover the service.

Use the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510953/calling-asmx-from-c-sharp-server-side-endpoint-element-matching-this-contract-c)

Answer (score 0):

You can also generate a proxy class by using the [wsdl utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/7h3ystb6(v=vs.100).aspx). You can find the utility in your Microsoft SDKs directory e.g. `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools` (vary depending on .NET version)

Use command line `wsdl http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL` in the directory to generate the proxy class.