# Android issue with HttpWebRequest/HttpClient

Tags: c#, android, web-services, xamarin

I have asp.net web service. The web service has url like this:
 `mydomain dot com/service.asmx/getlocation?id=100`

I always get below error. I tried both synchronous and async ways. I even tried to use Google.com but I always get below error:

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> ```
> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
> ```

My code looks like this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Timeout = 60000;
request.Method = "GET";

// I get error here 
using (WebResponse response =  request.GetResponse())
{
    // Get a stream representation of the HTTP web response:
    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        // Use this stream to build a JSON document object:
        JsonValue jsonDoc = await Task.Run(() => JsonObject.Load(stream));
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Response: {0}", jsonDoc.ToString());

        // Return the JSON document:
        return jsonDoc;
    }
}
```

Thanks

**Edit**:

I tried it on different emulators- Nexus 7 Lollipop(5.1.0) and Nexus S(4.4.2)

Comment: HTTP 500 means that it is a problem that occurred on the web service itself. It might be caused by lack of error handling due to bad input.

Comment: I m using web service like a url. Is it bad approach? Also, the input to web service is not bad, I can print url and check in browser and it shows me correct result while with my app, it is throwing error

Comment: Try this approach, just to make sure the problem in in the web service not how the client is set up. [Top answer of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510953/calling-asmx-from-c-sharp-server-side-endpoint-element-matching-this-contract-c) although error 500 is pretty clear.

Comment: Also noticing... It seems that returning JSON from a SOAP Service is quite tricky, I have looked at this stackoverflow question [How to let an ASMX file output json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211348/how-to-let-an-asmx-file-output-json)

Comment: You can use Newtonsoft.Json api.

Comment: Thanks @JoséMaría Your help solved my problem.

Comment: Ok, do you mind if I put that as a answer and you mark is as correct? For the sake of correctness when people look at this question in the future.